# Buttons not visible in UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I want to import a document into my application. I have created a Demo to import Document. A demo is working. below is the code of the Demo to open `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

```
-(IBAction) btnOpenClicked{
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:[self allowedUTIs] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
    documentPicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:true completion:nil];
}

-(NSArray*)allowedUTIs{
    return @[@"public.data",@"public.content",@"public.audiovisual-content",@"public.movie",@"public.audiovisual-content",@"public.video",@"public.audio",@"public.text",@"public.data",@"public.zip-archive",@"com.pkware.zip-archive",@"public.composite-content",@"public.text"];
}
```

The same code is implemented in my actual project. UIDocumentPickerViewController open and App is able to import file but the issue is that in the actual app I am not able to see any buttons in the header.  thought there is action happen but buttons are not visible. Please check screenshot of the Demo and actual app. 

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 7):

Your app is probably setting a global `UINavigationBar` tint color appearance. You can just reset the appearance for `UIDocumentPickerViewController` only by putting this code somewhere in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function and the bar buttons will return to their original blue.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
}
```

Comment: Can this not be done on iOS 10? I am trying to do the same but with instance of UIDocumentPickerViewController, but that doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: Not sure about iOS 10, maybe try to inspect the view controller hierarchy to see which one contain the navigation items using a tool like Reveal.

Comment: Hm, no, doesn't give me any more information. Thanks though!

Comment: is any solution is there for ios 9,same issue

Comment: can you what will be the syntax in objective c??

Answer (score 0):

**For Objective C:**

-> by putting this code somewhere in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[[UINavigationBar 
    appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:
      @[[UIDocumentBrowserViewController class]]] setTintColor: nil];
```